# open page cordova iOS not working with HTML content

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to open a separate window in my cordova app, with HTML content, not with a link. It doesn't work on the iOS device, it works when I run it in the browser.

My code is something like:

```
var win = window.open("", '_blank', "location=yes, directories=no, status=yes, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes");
win.document.body.innerHTML = "<p>HTML</p>";
```

Wen i run it, it seems like it's opening a page with transparent background.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code for iOS. Not sure about chrome version but from v53 it's not working.

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com";
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute("href",url);
a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
var dispatch = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
dispatch.initEvent("click", true, true);
a.dispatchEvent(dispatch);
return false;
```

Comment: The thing is thai I need to fill the page with html content, not provide an URL.